# .NET / C# - Allow overflowing of integers

Tags: c#, .net, integer, overflow

Recently i started making a item container, and every time the user tries to add an item into the container. If somehow the same item type exists, it'll stack them on top of each other, but there's a limit, which is `int.MaxValue` and if i tried:

```
if (2147483647 + 2147483647 > int.MaxValue)
```

That would give me the following error:

```
The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode
```

So i tried to use the unchecked keyword like so:

```
unchecked
{
     if (2147483647 + 2147483647 > int.MaxValue)
     {
     }
}
```

but this doesn't show trigger the if statement at all (I'm guessing it's wrapped around a Logical AND operator?)

Is there other ways to do this? (without using something like a int64, etc)

Comment: why are you adding two constants that are equal to int.MaxValue and comparing them to int.MaxValue?

Comment: @GregS, this is just an example.

Comment: what is the exact question, of course two int.MaxValues are larger than int.MaxValue.

Comment: Are you worrying about this just in case someone adds over 2 billion items of the same type into your list? Is this something that might actually happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an int operation overflows its not going to test greater than `Int32.MaxValue`.

If you want that condition to be true, use longs.

```
if (2147483647L + 2147483647L > int.MaxValue) ...
```

Alternatively, use `uint`s.

```
if (2147483647U + 2147483647U > (uint)int.MaxValue) ...
```

Comment: or you could note, as the compiler no doubt will, that the condition is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting both to uint (unsigned) if you don't need the negative half of the bitspace. Same bit width, just doesn't roll negative after Int.MaxValue (eg, it's 2x the magnitude of int.MaxValue)

Answer (score 0):

Throw it into an unchecked block:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your if condition isn't getting is because the addition of `2147483647 + 2147483647` will result in `-2` because of overflows of `int` in the `unchecked` block.

This is the reason your if condition `2147483647 + 2147483647 > int.MaxValue` is never going to be true because it'll get evaluated to `-2 > int.MaxValue`, which isn't true.